# How to perform a mapping with mapstruct that is dependant on more than one DTO variable

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct to map my DTO to its corresponding entity.

The DTO contains a Hashmap variable, the entries of which are suppossed to be mapped to a key- and a value-variable of a special HashMap-entity. That's why I am describing this mapping in an extra method as follows:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

      MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

      @Mapping(source = "myHashMap", target = "myHashMapEntityList", qualifiedByName = "mapMyHashMap")
      MyEntity mapToEntity(MyDTO dto);

      @Named("mapMyHashMap")
      static List<myHashMapEntity> mapMyHashMap(final Map<String, String> myHashMap) {
          ...
      }
}
```

This works fine. The only issue that I have is that I do not want to map all entries of the hashmap. I only want to map entries, the key of which is contained in a list `keysToBeMappedList`. While it is possible to construct this `keysToBeMappedList` from the `dto`, this variable is not part of the dto. And I am wondering how perform my mapping.

My question:

Is it possible to compute this `keysToBeMappedList` inside this `MyMapper` interface and then use this list inside the `mapMyHashMap` method? Because even if this is not possible and I make the `keysToBeMappedList` part of my dto, I will still have to use both `keysToBeMappedList` and `myHashMap` inside `mapMyHashMap` to perform the mapping. And I have never seen more than one variable being used in these mapstruct methods.

I hope it's more or less clear what I want to do. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression to call any method

```
  MyEntity mapToEntity(MyDTO dto, List<String> list);



 @Mapping(target = "name", expression = "java(mapMyHashMap(map, list))")
```

Or else if you don't need it to be configured, just hard code it in the method and do a filter out

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add more arguments to the methods:

```
import org.mapstruct.Context;
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

      MyMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(MyMapper.class);

      @Mapping(source = "myHashMap", target = "myHashMapEntityList", qualifiedByName = "mapMyHashMap")
      MyEntity mapToEntity(MyDTO dto, @Context List<String> keysToBeMappedList);

      @Named("mapMyHashMap")
      static List<myHashMapEntity> mapMyHashMap(final Map<String, String> myHashMap, @Context List<String> keysToBeMappedList) {
          ...
      }
}
```

The implementation of the `mapToEntity` method will now pass on the `keysToBeMappedList` to the `mapMyHashMap` method, but mapstruct will not attempt to use the `keysToBeMappedList` for any mappings.

[You can find more information about the @Context here.](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#passing-context)